# Show popup activity only once the app starts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, popup

I have added a `popup activity` inside my app which is popping after 15 seconds of my app start. But when I am opening another `activity` and coming back to my `main activity` the popup showing again. I want it to appear only the first time when user is opening the app. What changes I should make? Appreciate the help.

Here is the popup code:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override

        public void run() {


       if (context != null) {

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle)
                        .setTitle("Title")
                        .setMessage("Message")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        });

                mDialog = alert.create();
                mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle;
                if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
                mDialog.show();
                // .setIcon(R.drawable.inr1)
                // .show();

            }
        }
    }, 15000);
```

Comment: you can maintain a boolean variable in sharedPrefrances for that.

Comment: you want only one time action  or every time when user open application

Comment: dismiss you pop up at `onResume`

Comment: Put this code inside `onCreate()` if it isn't. If that isn't the case you can always keep a `boolean` in `SharedPreference`or you can keep a static variable in the class and set it to `true` or `false` according to you logic. The next time the activity start it should not run that code that's in `if` statement.

Comment: @koutuk I want this action to be done every time user open the application but just for once.

Comment: @NaserShaikh how to maintain boolean variable in sharedPreference? Where should I put the sharedPreference code?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if it needs to pop up only on application start

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

         //Set some flag on global constant

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

save a boolean inside sharedpreferences read its value and determine weather running for the first time or not.

here is the code that will help you.

```
public void firstimeRun(boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPrefrenceManager();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("key", value).apply();
}


public boolean isRunningForthefirstTime() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPrefrenceManager();
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key", false);
}


private SharedPreferences getPrefrenceManager() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: call these methods in your MainActivity, save the value and show dialog by reading these values from sharedprefs with conditional code.

Answer (score 0):

save a tag(counter)  in sharedPrefrances for that When the application starts up interpretation is the first time app start

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable in the application class like this.

```
public class global extends Application

// some Boolean variable to hold status
```

And make sure you put this class inside android manifests application tag

```
android:name
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IS_FIRST_TIME", true)) {
        //show your dialog here
        //...
        //change the value of your sharedPreferences
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("IS_FIRST_TIME", false).apply();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the activity lifecycle.

Note:Remove Handler.
Note 2:Create method and call the dialog 
Note 3:check the below method in lifecycle.

onPause ():
Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to onResume(). When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.

Answer (score 0):

Type finish(); after your startActivity(intent);